# Visual Studio:Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Cannot pull to integrate changes: Pull comand disabled

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

Hello Currently I have a flask web project that I want to push to a bitbucket repisitory. I am trying to Push to this repisotory to a BitBucket repistory of my team. T**he only files there so far is the Readme.md and the GitIgnore**

However, every time I try to push: I get this error:

```
> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository:
> rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch
> is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before
> pushing again. Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See
> the Output window for more details. Pushing master
```

**The thing is I kind of cannot pull integrate those remote chances because my pull command is disabled.**

How can I solve this simply?

So to Califiry I am working in an Existing Project and added a source control where I connected to the BitBucker Repisotry.

**I have tried to do this by cloning the Repisitory first and then adding this existing project by "adding existing project". But I no longer get the Debug Options therefore I am doing this directly from the project**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same error here - corrected by just using the push --force option if your bitbucket or other repo is empty:

```
git push -u --force origin master
```